# Search for sites I am a member of

Tags: search, search-results

How would I create a search webpart (search results?) that would display all the Team sites I am a member off? Trying to create a 'My Dashboard' landing page for all users of the sharepoint service.

Comment: Member as in contribute/edit permissions? While all the search results are already security trimmed (read permissions and above), you could create a query to list all sites or site collections that are based on the teamsite template.

Comment: Are you allow to use custom coding or just ootb coding ?

Comment: You can refer to this blog which explains how search is used to find access of current member
http://www.ilikesharepoint.de/2012/11/sharepoint-2010-display-all-sites-i-have-access-fast-and-easy-way/

Comment: @MonicaJagani that links shows only how to get sites the user is allowed to see, not sites where user is a member

Comment: To add to @Christoffer's answer. From that raw list you could then (while being  a quite hefty operation) make a request to each of the sites with e.g. REST to check users permission on that site and based on that trim what you do render to the user

Comment: Hi - basically I want to build a search result that displays links to all the Sites that user is allowed to see (so both visitor as well as Member or Owner Group Membership). We have different Site Collections/Templates so would like to lists TeamSites as well as Publishing Sites and Community and enterprise Wiki Sites.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this search to find all the entries in the sites membership lists for the the current user

```
MemberOWSUSER:{User.Name}
```

Then create a custom Search Display template that only displays the site title, and the site url (trimmed from the item url)

```
<html xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882"> 
<head>
<title>Member of</title>

<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
<mso:TemplateHidden msdt:dt="string">0</mso:TemplateHidden>
<mso:MasterPageDescription msdt:dt="string">Displays sites that the current user is a member of</mso:MasterPageDescription>
<mso:ContentTypeId msdt:dt="string">0x0101002039C03B61C64EC4A04F5361F385106603</mso:ContentTypeId>
<mso:TargetControlType msdt:dt="string">;#SearchResults;#</mso:TargetControlType>
<mso:HtmlDesignAssociated msdt:dt="string">1</mso:HtmlDesignAssociated>
<mso:ManagedPropertyMapping msdt:dt="string">'SiteTitle':'SiteTitle','Path':'Path'</mso:ManagedPropertyMapping>
<mso:HtmlDesignConversionSucceeded msdt:dt="string">True</mso:HtmlDesignConversionSucceeded>
<mso:HtmlDesignStatusAndPreview msdt:dt="string">http://uat.groupgovernance.cimic.com.au/sites/uat-mf/_catalogs/masterpage/Display%20Templates/Search/iPKL_CoP_Item_MemberOf.html, Conversion successful.</mso:HtmlDesignStatusAndPreview>
</mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
</xml><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="Item_Default">
<!--#_ 
        if(!$isNull(ctx.CurrentItem) && !$isNull(ctx.ClientControl)){

            var title = ctx.CurrentItem.SiteTitle;
            var url = ctx.CurrentItem.Path.substring(0, ctx.CurrentItem.Path.indexOf('/Lists/Members/DispForm.aspx?ID='));

            var imageUrl = url + '/SiteAssets/community-image.png';
_#-->
        <div>
            <a href="_#= url =#_">
                <img src="_#= imageUrl =#_" onerror="this.style.display='none';" />
                <br/>
                _#= $htmlEncode(title) =#_
            </a>
        </div>
<!--#_ 
        } 
_#-->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```